# Getting duplicate results with the same _id in Mongoose find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To begin i'm making two queries to a mongodb database, as showed below

```
let getLevelsZones = async () => {
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + ' ' + '23:00:00.000Z';
    yesterday = yyyy_y + '-' + mm_y + '-' + dd_y + ' ' + '00:00:00.000Z';
    return LevelsZonesModel.find({
        building:"5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d",
        $and:[
            {date_created: {$gte: yesterday}},
            {date_created: {$lt: today}}
        ]
    });  
}

let getLevelsByZoneAndUtility = async (zone, utility) => {
    return LevelsZonesModel.find({
        building:"5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d",
        utility: utility,
        zone: zone,
        $and:[
            {date_created: {$gte: yesterday}},
            {date_created: {$lt: today}}
        ]
    })
}
```

Both queries are executed on the same collection, but the second query needs data from the first query to be executed later in the code (below).

```
 let levels_zones = await getLevelsZones();
        levels_zones.map(async (level_zone, i) => {  
            let levels_zone_utility = await getLevelsByZoneAndUtility(level_zone.zone, level_zone.utility);
            console.log(levels_zone_utility);
```

First i'm going through all the documents so I can use "level_zone" to manipulate the results but before that I use it a parameter for the second query and print it to the screen to test if it goes as i want.

Here's a part of the output needed to explain my problem

```
[
  {
    _id: 60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-05T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object],
      '20': [Object],
      '21': [Object],
      '22': [Object],
      '23': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 0.020000000000038654, cost_m3: 0.06919000000013371 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  },
  {
    _id: 60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-06T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 4.930000000000007, cost_m3: 17.055335000000024 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  }
]
[
  {
    _id: 60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-05T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object],
      '20': [Object],
      '21': [Object],
      '22': [Object],
      '23': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 0.020000000000038654, cost_m3: 0.06919000000013371 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  },
  {
    _id: 60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-06T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 4.930000000000007, cost_m3: 17.055335000000024 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  }
]
```

As you can see there's two arrays each one with two objets, that's I want to see but the problem is that both arrays are the same, so i'm getting duplicate results somehow and I'm struggling so hard to fix that. Just so you have an idea, the entire output is supposed to have 22 arrays each one with 2 objects, instead it has 44 arrays with the same amount of objects. I hope you can help me find a way to fix. Thank you.

EDIT: Here's an example (to clarify things) of what the query should return, assuming I choose a specific zone and utility as an example, but that's what should be returned for every zone and utility

[Query in Robo 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op6aJ.png)

Comment: Is the pair utility and zone unique across the LevelsZonesModel? Because I think is possible that if you have two differents elements on LevelsZonesModel, both with the same utility and zone values, seems natural that they are going to get duplicated on the final array, because you will query the same thing twice

Answer (score 0):

Looking your data, your problem seems that you have duplicated data with the same 'utility' and 'zone' values. Look at:

```
  {
    _id: 60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-05T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object],
      '20': [Object],
      '21': [Object],
      '22': [Object],
      '23': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 0.020000000000038654, cost_m3: 0.06919000000013371 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  }
```

```
  {
    _id: 60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-06T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 4.930000000000007, cost_m3: 17.055335000000024 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  }
```

Because each one of them belongs to LevelsZonesModel, you will iterate for both *60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e* and *60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33*. Because they have the same value, they made the same query to *getLevelsByZoneAndUtility*, with values (east-building, agua-potavel),  which will give you the same result

```
[
  {
    _id: 60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-05T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-06T22:49:18.251Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object],
      '20': [Object],
      '21': [Object],
      '22': [Object],
      '23': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 0.020000000000038654, cost_m3: 0.06919000000013371 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  },
  {
    _id: 60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33,
    building: '5ef076a507f9cc56cb8d957d',
    date: 2021-06-06T23:00:00.000Z,
    utility: 'agua-potavel',
    zone: 'east-building',
    __v: 0,
    date_created: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    date_modified: 2021-06-07T18:08:12.660Z,
    hours: {
      '0': [Object],
      '1': [Object],
      '2': [Object],
      '3': [Object],
      '4': [Object],
      '5': [Object],
      '6': [Object],
      '7': [Object],
      '8': [Object],
      '9': [Object],
      '10': [Object],
      '11': [Object],
      '12': [Object],
      '13': [Object],
      '14': [Object],
      '15': [Object],
      '16': [Object],
      '17': [Object],
      '18': [Object],
      '19': [Object]
    },
    metrics: { m3: 4.930000000000007, cost_m3: 17.055335000000024 },
    sources: { '5ef0e45607f9cc56cb8d9689': [Object] }
  }
]
```

So you have one array related to the query of element id 60bc054427adeb5f5fc8160e, and other array for the query of element id 60bd5afd27adeb5f5f18ae33, which are the same query, and because of that, the same result.

So that's the reason of results being duplicated. If they were 3 documents with the same utility and zone, you will have tripled data, and so on.

Comment: Both utility and zone are supposed to be repeated, there's a few documents that belong to the same utility and zone, also have the same building. My point here is that I was waiting for an array with different objects and not two like I showed in the second example, if you look closely in the first array both _id of the objects are different but in the second they're the same, that array is repeated twice and I only need it once. I still don't get why is it happening

Comment: What returns: ``` let levels_zones = await getLevelsZones(); console.log(levels_zones.length) ```?

Comment: Basically returns all the results similar to the second example but each one is unique in terms of _id, the lenght is 22.

Comment: That's very weird, because the length of the array  levels_zones.map should be equal to the length level_zones. Could you add the following to debug a little bit more: ```let levels_zones = await getLevelsZones();
        levels_zones.map(async (level_zone, i) => {  
            console.log(level_zone._id)
            let levels_zone_utility = await getLevelsByZoneAndUtility(level_zone.zone, level_zone.utility);
            console.log(levels_zone_utility);```. Are the _ids unique?

Comment: Or actually: Is there any strange thing on that output regarding the ids?

Comment: And also, could you edit and complete the async arrow function of tha array's map function?. It ends after the console.log with a return, or there is more processing being done?